# Сложение со сдвигом (кумулятивное суммирование)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть dataframe

```
      X    Y
 0    0    0
 1    3    24
 2    5    300
 3    3   -10
 4    5    40
```

Мне нужно получить поле Y_new в этом dataframe, в котором значение 
Y_new[0] = Y[0], Y_new[1] = Y_new[0]+Y[1], Y_new[2] = Y_new[1]+Y[2],
Y_new[3] = Y_new[2]+Y[3], Y_new[4] = Y_new[3]+Y[4]

```
    X    Y    Y_new
0   0    0    0
1   3    24   24
2   5    300  324
3   3   -10   310
4   5    40   350
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [Series.cumsum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
In [155]: df['Y_new'] = df['Y'].cumsum()

In [156]: df
Out[156]:
   X    Y  Y_new
0  0    0      0
1  3   24     24
2  5  300    324
3  3  -10    314
4  5   40    354
```